# Decomposition Theorem for Posets

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders

There is in module theory the following (krull-shmidt) theorem:

If $(M_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(N_j)_{j\in J}$ are two families of simple module such that $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} M_i \simeq \bigoplus\limits_{j\in J} M_j$, then there exists a bijection $\sigma:I\rightarrow J$ such that $M_i \simeq N_{\sigma(i)}$.

Is there a similar kind of theorem for partially ordered sets? More precisely, is there a class of 'simple' partial orders such that if $(P_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(Q_j)_{j\in J}$ are 'simple' orders such that 
$\prod\limits_i P_i \simeq \prod\limits_j Q_j$, then there exists a bijection $\sigma:I \rightarrow J$ such that $P_i \simeq Q_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: How are you defining the order on $\prod\limits_i P_i$? Lexigraphically?

Comment: The standard ordering: $(x_i) \leq (y_i)$ iff $\forall i\in I(x_i \leq y_i)$

Comment: As orders go, that is one of the less useful. I'd hardly call it "standard".

Comment: In the category of partially ordered sets and order-preserving maps, $\prod\limits_i P_i$ together with that ordering is the product of $(P_i)$ - this is what I mean by standard.

Comment: In the second line, I suppose you mean $\bigoplus_{i \in I}M_i \simeq \bigoplus_{j \in J} N_j$.

Comment: Thats true, but  I do still mean product. Since if $(P_i)$ and $(G_i)$ are connected partial orders such that $\amalg_iP_i \simeq \amalg_j G_j$, then there exists a bijection $\sigma: I\rightarrow J$ such that $P_i \simeq G_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: Same works for topological spaces: if $(X_i)$ and $(Y_j)$ are connected topological spaces, such that $\amalg_i X_i \simeq \amalg_j Y_j$, then there exists a bijection $\sigma: I\rightarrow J$ such that $X_i \simeq Y_{\sigma(i)}$.

Comment: @StefanPerko - yes. Doing so is often quite useful. However, now that my terminological quibble has been adequately answered. Please let us  move on. I have no argument with the question, now that I know what it means.

Comment: I suppose you mean 'indecomposable module', not 'simple module.'

Comment: No I mean simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question concerns identifying a class of partial orders whose products have unique factorizations. I will give positive and negative partial answers, both (co)authored by Hashimoto.

The positive answer may be found in

> Hashimoto, Junji
> On direct product decomposition of partially ordered sets.
> Ann. of Math. (2) 54, (1951). 315-318.

Here it is proved that 
any two direct product decompositions of a connected poset have a common refinement. Arbitrary products of connected orders are not always connected, but they are sometimes connected. Thus, one can almost take the word *simple* in the original question to mean *connected and directly indecomposable*. For example, you can take *simple* to mean *connected and directly indecomposable* if you are only concerned about finite products of posets.

The negative result (from an earlier paper of Hashimoto and Nakayama) concerns the nonconnected case. Hashimoto and Nakayama point out that $(1+x)(1+x^2+x^4)=(1+x^3)(1+x+x^2)$, and translate this fact into a statement about posets by letting $1={\bf 1}$ stand for the $1$-element chain, $x={\bf 2}$ stand for the $2$-element chain, multiplication stand for cartesian product, and sum stand for disjoint (parallel) sum.

In other words, there is an isomorphism $A\times B\cong C\times D$ where $A = {\bf 1}+{\bf 2}$ is the disjoint sum of a $1$-element chain and a $2$-element chain, $B={\bf 1}+{\bf 2}^2+{\bf 2}^4$, 
$C = {\bf 1}+{\bf 2}^3$, and $D = {\bf 1}+{\bf 2}+{\bf 2}^2$. Hashimoto and Nakayama argue that these factorizations have no common refinement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I think you mean directly irreducible and connected, no? Since connectedness is not enough to get that the factors are pair-wise isomorphic.

Comment: For the non-connected case, just not that any set  $X$ together with $=$ is a partial order, and function between sets preserves equality. So if $A = 2$ and $B = 6$ and $C = 4$ and $D = 3$, then $A \times B \simeq C \times D$.

Comment: Re first comment: yes, I will edit. Re second comment: in the Hashimoto-Nakayama example, the factors are directly indecomposable. Not so when the factors are discrete.

Comment: Ok thanks! By the way, do you have a counter-example at hand for why it is the case that an infinite product of connected orders in not necessarily connected?

Comment: Counterexample: Let $P_i$, $i=1,2,3,\ldots$ be a connected poset with distinguished elements $a_i, b_i$ whose shortest connecting path has length $i$. In $\prod P_i$ the elements $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ have no connecting path.

Comment: Thanks again for the great answer @Keith Kearnes, it has been very helpful!